# Reshape and mean calculation

Tags: r, reshape, mean, temporal

I have climatic data which have been collected during a whole year along an altitude gradient. Shaped like that:

```
clim <- read.table(text="alti    year    month    week    day    meanTemp    maxTemp    minTemp
350     2011    aug.     31      213    10          14         6
350     2011    aug.     31      214    12          18         6
350     2011    aug.     31      215    10          11         9
550     2011    aug.     31      213    8           10         6
550     2011    aug.     31      214    10          12         8
550     2011    aug.     31      215    8           9          7
350     2011    sep.     31      244    9           10         8
350     2011    sep.     31      245    11          12         10
350     2011    sep.     31      246    10          11         9
550     2011    sep.     31      244    7.5         9          6
550     2011    sep.     31      245    8           10         6
550     2011    sep.     31      246    8.5         9          8", header=TRUE)
```

and I am trying to reshape this data in order to have only one row per altitude and to calculate the mean data for each month and for the whole year. I would be great if it could be shaped like that:

```
alti    mean_year(meanTemp)   mean_year(maxTemp)   mean_aug.(meanTemp)   mean_aug.(maxTemp)   mean_sep.(meanTemp)   [...]
350     10.333                12.667               10.667                14.3                 10                     ...
550     8.333                 9.833                8.667                 10.333               7.766                  ...
```

Any idea to perform this reshaping & calculation?

Comment: Can you modify the data into a more user friendly for that we can copy/paste into our own sessions (using `dput` for example)?

Comment: Hi Roman, user198275 has just modified the data so it's now easy to paste in R. I didn't know that it was possible, great!! ;)   R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another variation of `data.table` solution, but this requires the current [`devel version, v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
setDT(clim)
form = paste("alti", c("year", "month"), sep=" ~ ")
val  = c("meanTemp", "maxTemp")
ans  = lapply(form, function(x) dcast(clim, x, mean, value.var = val))
Reduce(function(x, y) x[y, on="alti"], ans)

#    alti meanTemp_mean_2011 maxTemp_mean_2011 meanTemp_mean_aug. meanTemp_mean_sep. maxTemp_mean_aug. maxTemp_mean_sep.
# 1:  350          10.333333         12.666667          10.666667                 10          14.33333         11.000000
# 2:  550           8.333333          9.833333           8.666667                  8          10.33333          9.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use data.table and dcast:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(clim)

merge(

clim[, list("mean_temp_mean_year" = mean(meanTemp), "max_temp_mean_year" = mean(maxTemp)), by = alti]
,
dcast(clim[, list("mean_temp_mean" = mean(meanTemp), "max_temp_mean" = mean(maxTemp)), by = c("alti","month")], alti ~ month, value.var = c("mean_temp_mean","max_temp_mean"))
,
by = "alti")
```

I've switched the names of some of the variables, and you col order is not perfect, but the can be reordered/renamed afterwards

Answer (score 1):

To get the means of the months or years, you can use `aggregate` followed by  `reshape`.

The two aggregates can be computed separately, and then `merge` puts them together:

```
mon <- aggregate(cbind(meanTemp, maxTemp) ~ month + alti, data=clim, FUN=mean)
mon.wide <- reshape(mon, direction='wide', timevar='month', idvar='alti')

yr <- aggregate(cbind(meanTemp, maxTemp) ~ year + alti, data=clim, FUN=mean)
yr.wide <- reshape(yr, direction='wide', timevar='year', idvar='alti')
```

Each of these `.wide` sets have the data that you want.  The only common column is `alti` so we take the `merge` defaults:

```
 merge(mon.wide, yr.wide)
##   alti meanTemp.aug. maxTemp.aug. meanTemp.sep. maxTemp.sep. meanTemp.2011 maxTemp.2011
## 1  350     10.666667     14.33333            10    11.000000     10.333333    12.666667
## 2  550      8.666667     10.33333             8     9.333333      8.333333     9.833333
```

Comment: This solution does not provide a complete answer. It lacks of the aggregate values by years only.